Relation between Apache Ignite's REPLICATED and PARTITIONED with BACKUP FLag
Apache Ignite supports REPLICATED and PARTITIONED caches.
If there are 3 Embedded Server Ignite

Node 1, 2, 3 and Cache is defined as PARTITIONED, with READTHROUGH with RDBMS Table

Data is inserted in Node 1 Application to Distributed Cache,
while we are trying to get from Node 3, it was returning null / going to the Cache Store and at the same time our  Cache data is not expired.
Can we get a clear explanation how this PARTITIONED works when BACKUPS=0?
What about other node, will Node 3 fetch from Node 1?

You mention 3 "Embedded Server Ignite" nodes. If these three nodes make up a cluster then with a partitioned cache each node will have ~1/3 of the 1024 partitions created when the cache gets created. In a 3 node "CLUSTER" when a call is made to find a key the hash of the key is taken and the result of the hash is which partition the data will reside in. The client also knows which host has which partition. As a result, all data elements (keys) are NEVER more than 1 level on indirection from the client. By contrast if your nodes do not make up a "CLUSTER" then the other nodes will never know anything about data that is on some other Ignite node / cluster. You can tell if your nodes form a cluster. After your server nodes have all started you will see a console log such as the following:
[14:51:31] Topology snapshot [ver=3, locNode=e9eac792, servers=3, clients=0, state=INACTIVE, CPUs=12, offheap=0.18GB, heap=3.0GB]
[14:51:31]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=3, online=3, offline=0]
[14:51:31]   ^-- All baseline nodes are online, will start auto-activation
By contrast a REPLICATE cache will copy all data to all nodes in the cluster. A replicated cache should typically only be used for small tables (caches) with data that changes only rarely.
Hope that helps.



WHat is the use of Backup Flag - if the cache mode is REPLICATED, as by REPLICATED, it is going to copy data to all Nodes [


is Backup Property is applicable only for PARTITIONED Cache?



Yes, the backup property is not relevant for REPLICATED tables.

@stephen Darlington - Thanks for clarification


What about other node, will Node 3 fetch from Node 1?

Yes, inserted data is eventually visible to all nodes. Ignite will route the request to correct node from any client or embedded API call.
See also CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.
